# How to determine if a variable is an empty object, empty array or empty string?

Tags: javascript, is-empty

I have an object whose keys can have have values which can be object, string or array.

```
const obj = {
  key1: 'asdf',
  key2: {},
  key3: ['a','b','c'],
  key4: [],
  key5: '',
}
```

I have to filter all the keys which are empty i.e empty objects, empty array or empty string.

Is there any other way than writing conditions based on `typeof` of keys and then checking null ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use Object.keys()

```js
if (Object.keys(something).length) console.log("Not empty");
```

This works for all of strings, arrays, and of course, objects.

You can check the Object.keys documentation for more details, specifically, the [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#using_object.keys) section and the [non-object coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#non-object_coercion) section, which state:

> ```
> // simple array const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
> console.log(Object.keys(arr)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']
>
> // array-like object const obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
> console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // console: ['0', '1', '2']
> ```

and

> In ES5, if the argument to this method is not an object (a
> primitive), then it will cause a TypeError.
>
> From ES2015 onwards, a non-object argument will be coerced to an
> object.
>
> ```
> // In ES5 Object.keys('foo');  // TypeError: "foo" is not an object
>
> // In ES2015+ Object.keys('foo');  // ["0", "1", "2"]
> ```

Comment: but not for numbers

Comment: But numbers can't be empty in the first place. Besides the question clearly states: `which can be object, string or array.`

Comment: If you use this test as a blanket `is empty` then all numbers are empty, but your point that the OP is only looking for string/object/array is fair. (also 0 is falsy, is that empty?)

Answer (score 1):

For empty strings simple compare the property to `""`.
comparing for empty objects and empty arrays can be done using comparing the `Object.keys` of the property length compared to 0.

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 'asdf',
  key2: {},
  key3: ['a','b','c'],
  key4: [],
  key5: '',
}

function filterObject(obj) {
    for (var propName in obj) {
        if (obj[propName] === "" || Object.keys(obj[propName]).length === 0) {
            delete obj[propName];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log(filterObject(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Loop over the `keys` of object `obj` using `Object.keys` and set the properties of new object only if it is not empty

You can check for the type of value using `typeof` operator

**1)** `string`: `typeof` will return `string` and check for the `length` property

**2)** `array`: You can use `Array.isArray` and it will return `boolean` value whether the object is an array or not

**3)** `object`: You can first get all keys using `Object.keys` and then check if there is any property exist on that object or not using `length` property

Since, `arrays` are `object` in JS, so you can directly use

```
(typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length)
```

to check where it is an object and if it contain any property or not

You can create a filter as

```
if (value !== "" && Object.keys(value).length) acc[key] = value;
```

```js
const obj = {
  key1: "asdf",
  key2: {},
  key3: ["a", "b", "c"],
  key4: [],
  key5: "",
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const value = obj[key];
  if (value !== "" && Object.keys(value).length) acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 'asdf',
  key2: {},
  key3: ['a','b','c'],
  key4: [],
  key5: '',
}
Object.keys(obj).map(dt => {if (!obj[dt].length) delete obj[dt]});

console.log(obj)
```